# Is it (currently) possible to share games between users on different computers?

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

In `Steam -> Settings -> Account` I now have button `Manage family sharing & devices`.

However it seem that there only thing I can do is authorize sharing on same device. Description says pretty much same thing. However, from the original Family Sharing announcement I was under impression that it would allow me authorizing a user on other machine.

- Is that currently possible?
- If not, is there any official information regarding the question?

Just to make it clear, I'm looking for an option, that would be easier than physically going to each machine to log in and authorize.

Comment: I know there are definitely people who are sharing games between accounts, I just don't know how it works, exactly.

Comment: @Unionhawk: I know that sharing will work if you log in with the other account on that machine and authorize sharing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can share accounts by logging onto their device, and authorizing it. Once you have done that they can play on your library.

[image]

If you are talking about people in long-distance you will have to use a VNC to access their computer in order to sign-in and authorize their device. I highly recommend only doing this with people you trust.

You can cancel the authorization at any time.

Laptop Example: I authorized my laptop so people could access my library on it if they logged onto their accounts.

Multiple-Authorization Example: If three of my friends authorize their accounts on my laptop I'll be able to access their libraries.

Keep in mind though that only one person can play any library at any given time. However if it is your own library you want to access you can kick the person who is currently using it out in order to play on it.

It is still in Beta so I cannot say for certain but as it stands right now no. There have been a number of complaints petitions about this because people do not like the idea of having to travel far in order to grant access to their library to a friend. The only solution for long-distance seems to be using a VNC to access their computer remotely.

@vartec it's official that there isn't, but we won't know whether it will change until the feature is fully released. See http://steamcommunity.com/groups/familysharing/discussions/0/846964363934331891/

Comment: Is it official that there isn't and won't be other option to do that?

Comment: It is still in Beta so I cannot say for certain but as it stands right now no. There have been a number of complaints petitions about this because people do not like the idea of having to travel far in order to grant access to their library to a friend. The only solution for long-distance seems to be using a VNC to access their computer remotely.

Comment: @vartec it's official that there isn't, but we won't know whether it will change until the feature is fully released. See http://steamcommunity.com/groups/familysharing/discussions/0/846964363934331891/

Comment: @Astralchaos: if you add that comment and 3ventic's comment into the answer I'll mark that as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can - in order to set it up, you need to log into each computer that you want to authorise the sharing of games on. To do this, log in to the computer you want to enable sharing on and go to Steam -> Settings -> Account -> Manage Family Sharing & Devices. This will show the following window:

[image]

From here you can click 'Authorize device' to allow users that log in to Steam on that computer to access your game library.

To deauthorise a device, simply browse to this same screen, select the device you want to deauthorise and the 'Authorize' button will become a 'Deauthorize' button. Click it to revoke access.

As for remotely authorising another computer without giving out your credentials, this is not currently available but it is worthwhile keeping in mind that this functionality is still reasonably early in the beta stage. Currently the only way around this would be to use remote desktop functionality like Windows' Remote Desktop, Team Viewer, VNC, LogMeIn, etc, to remotely log into Steam on the other computer(s) and authorise them in the above manner. Deauthorising a computer can be done from anywhere, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) to log into your account on your friend's computer, then authorize your friend's device while logged into your own account on their machine in the menu you mentioned. Then you should log out and they can log in and play your games.